# Dyno memory size, does it include system resources?

Tags: heroku

A quick question

When looking at heroku dynos, they have say, 512 MB of ram.

My question is, is this 512 MB of ram to be used by my application alone, or does it also include other system resources out of my control?

For example, using other VPS hosting services, I can get 4GB ram fairly cheap, but the memory is shared between by application and other system resources